# How to get a pod restart dates history?

Tags: kubernetes

I restarted a pod in my kubernetes cluster but I feel like that someone rollbacked it because when I check, I see the last restarting date does not match with the date I restarted it.

What I want is to have all restart date history. Assume I restarted my pod yesterday and today, I want to have yesterday date and today date in my restart history. In this way I can be sure that someone restarted it after my restart

So my question is: Is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy built-in way to get the info that you want.

The best would probably built a specific service to provide this info if it is important for you. You could listen for Pod-changes and Events in a such service to collect the data that you need.